# All unit vector has bounded components?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, inequality

If $\Vert v_i\Vert \leq 1$ for all $1\leq i\leq k$ with $\{ v_1,..,v_k\}$ is linearly independent THEN FOR ALL real numbers $\alpha_i$ with $$\Vert \sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_iv_i\Vert=1$$ we can find $M>0$ such that $\vert\alpha_i \vert \leq M$ for all $1\leq i\leq k$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Let $V=\begin{bmatrix} v_1 \cdots v_k \end{bmatrix}$. Since the $v_i$ are linearly independent, the matrix $V^T V$ is invertible.

If $y = V \alpha$, we see that $V^T y = V^T V \alpha$ and hence $\alpha = (V^T V)^{-1} V^T y$. In particular, we have $\|\alpha \| \le M \|y\|$, where
$M = \|(V^T V)^{-1} V^T\|$.

Consequently, $\max_{\|V \alpha \| = 1} \|\alpha\|  = M$.

This is true for any consistent norms, choose $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha$ be the vector containing the $\alpha_i$s as entries. By padding it with zeros and extend $v_1,\ldots,v_k$ to a basis of the underlying vector space, the given condition can be rewritten in matrix form as $\|V\alpha\|=1$. Since all norms on a finite dimensional vector space are equivalent, $\|\cdot\|_\infty\le c\|\cdot\|$ for some $c>0$. It follows that
$$
\|\alpha\|_\infty
=\|V^{-1}V\alpha\|_\infty
\le \|V^{-1}\|_\infty\|V\alpha\|_\infty
\le \|V^{-1}\|_\infty\ c\|V\alpha\|
=c\|V^{-1}\|_\infty.
$$

Comment: $V$ is not necessarily square.